# Aumentar el java heap de JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

Alguien sabe como aumentar le tamaño de la memoria virtual del Wildfly 8. Lo que pasa es que estoy traficando archivos muy pesados por la red y en un momento dado me salta la excepción. Ya probé modificando el archivo standalone.conf:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx5120m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

y nada. Agradecería si alguien puede orientarme.

Comment: En lugar de copiar todo el archivo en memoria, podrías hacer *streaming*.

Comment: En realidad son informes, es decir, desde Java solicito un informe de transacciones con un rango de fechas a un programa cobol y este lo devuelve en un array, lo cual es lo que cargo en la tabla html. Pero en el momento de cargar el array ya lanza la excepción

Comment: ¿Qué longitud tiene el array, cuánta información está allí? ¿Será que tienes demasiada información en tu arreglo o que tu problema de memoria esté por otro lado?

Comment: pufff, es muy grande el array, si es de un mes tiene 80.000 aprox. registros con 27 columnas, siendo las columnas fijas, operando con java swing no tengo problemas porque me reconoce bien cuando aumento el java heap, pero en el servidor modifico el archivo standalone.conf pero todo indica que no toma ese valor que le modifico

Comment: otra consulta, wildfly 8 puede correr con Java 8? o hasta el Java 7 nomas soporta?